# Writable directories with rootless Podman

Tags: ansible, podman, rootless

I'm trying to run rootless Podman containers with

```bash
podman container create --name postgres --expose 5432 --memory 512M --hostname postgres --volume /home/user/some/path/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z,U --userns keep-id --env POSTGRES_USER=admin --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret docker.io/postgres:14
```

but I'm getting the error message

```
Error: error stat'ing file `/home/user/some/path/postgres`: Permission denied: OCI permission denied
```

The destination path `/home/user/some/path` is within a gocryptfs mount. Mapping the volume outside the path works flawlessly.

So far I thought that `--userns keep-id` should avoid permission issues for rootless containers but if I'm removing the option I'm getting the error message

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
```

As far as I understood, providing the options `--uidmap` and `--gidmap` could help as well but I'm not sure how I can provide the proper values for it.

Under the hood [I'm using Ansible to configure the containers](https://github.com/alexanderadam/podman_oci_permission_denied#creating-podman-bind-volume-within-user-mount).

**EDIT:** Now I also created [a Podman issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14488).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error was that the mount wasn't done with the [fuse parameter `allow_other`](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14488#issuecomment-1149886211).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you had done with /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid configuration, as it described here:

https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md

*Rootless Podman requires the user running it to have a range of UIDs listed in the files /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid.*

*...*

*The format of this file is USERNAME:UID:RANGE*

- *username as listed in /etc/passwd or in the output of getpwent.*
- *The initial UID allocated for the user.*
- *The size of the range of UIDs allocated for the user.*

Example:

```
# cat /etc/subuid
johndoe:100000:65536
test:165536:65536
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry, I missed to give an update: mounting outside the GoCryptFs mount works perfectly. I also created an [Podman issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14488). Furthermore I created [an Ansible repo](https://github.com/alexanderadam/podman_oci_permission_denied#creating-podman-bind-volume-within-user-mount) for easy reproducibility. I'm updating the original post accordingly.